# Does leveling in FFX-2 increase stats depending on active dresssphere?

Tags: final-fantasy-10-2

So if Yuna levels up while wearing the black mage dressphere, will magic be increased more often than strength?

And if so, does this mean that each character should be focused on a particular 'class' of dresses? (e.g. you master black mage first with Yuna, so you should only focus on other magic-casting dresspheres with her, and never venture into the fighting classes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dresssphere you equip does not affect your stat gains when leveling, which are random.<sup>1</sup>

It's hard to prove a negative, but the game is designed around switching dressspheres at will and such a mechanic would prove detrimental to that design philosophy.

Additionally, the official strategy guide makes no mention of such a mechanic, and neither of the two leveling guides<sup>2</sup> on [GameFAQs](http://gamefaqs.com) mention the mechanics, either.

#### Notes

<sup>Note 1:</sup>  Your dressspheres do, however, affect your current stats.
<sup>Note 2:</sup> "[Dressphere Stats by Level](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/562386-final-fantasy-x-2/faqs/29016)" by FFBeowulf and "[Level 99 Dress Sphere Data](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/562386-final-fantasy-x-2/faqs/23108)" by Kouli

Comment: Wow. A very thorough answer with sources too! Thank you Mark